# Fazer update de uma tabela em outra com where?

Tags: mysql

Tenho duas tabelas uma onde ficam os dados da ordem de compra e a segunda tabela onde fica os itens.

Tabela A

```
id | ordem_compra | fornecedor | data
```

Tabela B

```
id | ordem_compra | desc | qtdade | valor | status | data
```

Como o número de ordem de compra é fornecido pela fabricante do item, estava tudo funcionando até que uma outra industria acabou nos confirmando uma ordem de compra com o mesmo número de outra fábrica o que misturou os itens quando faço a consulta pelo número de OC.

Inseri mais uma coluna na tabela B com o código fornecedor, minha dúvida agora é a seguinte como inserir o código do fornecedor da tabela A na tabela B.

Tentei desta forma mas sem sucesso, qual a forma correta?

```
UPDATE tbl_b
SET tbl_b.fornecedor = 
(
     SELECT tbl_a.id_fornecedor FROM tbl_a c
     WHERE tbl_a.ordem_compra = c.ordem_compra
);
```

Comment: mas isso é necessário? pode colocar o fornecedor no pedido e os itens terem uma chave com a tabela de pedido, que se for um sequencial numérico não haverá problema, dai inclusive a tabela B não precisaria do num da ordem que já está na tabela A, evita essa duplicidade de informação, esse modelo não está normalizado corretamete

Comment: Da fato, a tabela B deveria ter uma chave estrangeira para um valor único da tabela A, possivelmente `tabela A.id`. Manter o valor da ordem de compra nas duas tabelas é um sinal de redundância, o que geralmente indica que a estrutura das tabelas não está da melhor forma.

Comment: Da maneira como você fez e, de acordo com sua afirmação, a ordem_compra pode ter o mesmo valor para diferentes fornecedores, então terá que também incluir fornecedor na tabela B. Mas já que você utiliza uma chave artificial (imagino que id seja uma chave artificial) então poderá utilizar tal campo para o relacionamento mas, eventualmente, poderá gerar algumas inconsistências que você terá que impedir através de código em sua aplicação (por. ex. diferentes id para o mesmo par ordem_compra - fornecedor) o que não ocorreria com o uso de chaves naturais.

Comment: Vocês tem razão posso colocar o id da tabela A na tabela B, mas não entendi como fazer esta query.

Comment: Editei a pergunta postando a forma que tentei fazer o insert mas sem sucesso, poderiam me orientar onde errei na query?

Comment: A tabela B deveria ter um campo id_tab_A que seria a chave estrangeira para o id da tabela A, e neste caso não seria necessário o campo ordem_compra na tabela B. Ou deveria também possuir o campo fornecedor,para o caso em que utilizasse chaves naturais. Em ambos os casos você precisa modificar a estrutura de sua tabela B e recarregar os dados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo o que eu entendi, você já tem os dados inseridos nas duas tabelas, só que agora você inseriu mais uma coluna na tabela B e quer inserir os fornecedores nessa nova coluna.
Neste caso, o certo seria fazer um update:

```
UPDATE tbl_b b, tbl_a a
   SET b.fornecedor = a.fornecedor
 WHERE b.ordem_compra = a.ordem_compra
```

Vale ressaltar que você deve ter cuidado ao aplicar o update, já que as duas tabelas parecem não estar normalizadas corretamente!

Comment: De fato me equivoquei e fiquei fazer um `INSERT` onde era `UPDATE`. Obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou perfeitamente, já editei a pergunta também.